# Excel spreadsheet like features development kit for KnockoutJs

Tags: knockout.js

I am looking forward to achieve excel spreadsheet like features development kit for KnockoutJS. Features like select cells rows wise/column wise and drag n drop on another cell/cells. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help in your code.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really ask a question and quite correctly pointed by @syfer, SO is about helping with your code.

However, there's a library called '[handsontable](https://handsontable.com)' which I believe may do / start to do what you're expecting. It basically allows you to do a lot of Excel / sheet formatting type things in the browser.

If you're looking to allow users to download Excel spreadsheets, I'd look at [ExcelJS](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs) for tables and formulas and [xlsx-chart](https://github.com/objectum/xlsx-chart) for charts.